# Use variable in JSON concatenated payload string

Tags: javascript, json, concatenation

The below payload works if I hardcode the pubblish date, but if I want to use a variable, it breaks, I can't get the correct way of adding a variable in the payload, I can't use template literals as the JS engine is prior to ES6.

```
var today = new Date();
var publishDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 31));
const query = JSON.stringify({query:
               '{' +
               '   all_insight_article(locale: "en-gb"'+
               '     where: {business_unit: {business_unit: {title: "Capital"}, MATCH: ALL}, audience: {MATCH: ALL, audiences: {title: "Management"}} publish_date_gt:'+publishDate+'}'+
               '   ) {items {'+
               '        system {uid publish_details {time} updated_at}'+
               '        absolute_url title subtitle main_image'+
               '        audienceConnection     {edges {node {... on Audiences   {title system {uid}}}}}'+
               '        article_typeConnection {edges {node {... on ArticleType {title}}}}'+
               '        topicsConnection       {edges {node {... on Topics      {title display_name system {uid}}}}}}total}}'
        });
```

Error:

```
07/03/2023 14:47:24 js3 []
07/03/2023 14:47:24 js3 INT-150012 The HTTP query returned a 'Unprocessable Entity' type error (422)
```

Comment: What is the value of `publishDate`?

Comment: Updated in code. @mikaf

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the actual problem, but maybe you have to quote it: `publish_date_gt:"'+publishDate+'"}`

Comment: Now I get an empty response @nulldev `07/03/2023 14:55:24 js3 []
07/03/2023 14:55:24 js3 Count 0`

Comment: Try `publish_date_gt:"'+publishDate.toISOString()+'"}` and check if the response is still empty

Comment: Nice NullDev, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75663546/use-variable-in-json-concatenated-payload-string#comment133484841_75663546) as answer:

`publishDate` is still a Date objects but the query expects a string. So you have to quote it and convert it to an ISO String ([Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)) first:

```
const query = JSON.stringify({query:
               '{' +
               '   all_insight_article(locale: "en-gb"'+
               '     where: {business_unit: {business_unit: {title: "Capital"}, MATCH: ALL}, audience: {MATCH: ALL, audiences: {title: "Management"}} publish_date_gt:"'+publishDate.toISOString()+'"}'+
               '   ) {items {'+
               '        system {uid publish_details {time} updated_at}'+
               '        absolute_url title subtitle main_image'+
               '        audienceConnection     {edges {node {... on Audiences   {title system {uid}}}}}'+
               '        article_typeConnection {edges {node {... on ArticleType {title}}}}'+
               '        topicsConnection       {edges {node {... on Topics      {title display_name system {uid}}}}}}total}}'
        });
```